# Vercel / Next.js creates a huge number of MongoDB connections when used with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel

I use Vercel with Next.js for a project I'm working on. I have some standard [Next.js API](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) routes that are called by the client app. Somehow, it's enough for a single user to visit the site for the number of MongoDB connections to grow by 50+. I often see the site having 200+ DB connections on my staging instances that only I use. How can I limit the number of connections or prevent it from growing so quickly?

My API calls are relatively straightforward, for example:

```
export const deletePost = async ({
  userId,
  postId,
}: {
  userId: string;
  postId: string;
}) => {
  await connectMongoose();
  await PostModel.deleteOne({ _id: postId, userId });
};
```

```
export const getDrafts = async ({ userId }: { userId: string }) => {
  await connectMongoose();

  const drafts = await DraftPostModel.find({ userId }).sort({ updatedAt: -1 });

  return drafts ? drafts.map((draft) => draft.toJSON()) : [];
};
```

I also use server-side rendering:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const id = await getOptionalAuthUserId(context);

  const {
    query: { draftId },
  } = context;

  const [privateUserData, draft] = await Promise.all([
    getPrivateUserData(id),
    getDraft({ userId: id!, draftId: draftId as string }),
  ]);

  return {
    props: {
      draft,
      privateUserData,
    },
  };
};
```

And static generation (although that should only affect the number of connections at build time:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {

  // Ignore weird Promise.all for a single call
  const [post] = await Promise.all([getSinglePost({ postId: POST_ID })]);

  if (!post) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
    revalidate: DEFAULT_REVALIDATION_TIME_IN_SECONDS,
  };
};
```

I'm assuming something may be off about the way I connect Mongoose but I can't see anything wrong with my code, I take care to cache and reuse connections. An important thing to note here is that when I log the code below, I only see the `connectMongoose` function called a few times but the number of connections increases by 50+ the moment I open the site.

```
import { ConnectionStates, connect } from "mongoose";

import { MONGODB_URI } from "@/utils";

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local",
  );
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */

// @ts-ignore
let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  // @ts-ignore
  cached = global.mongoose = { connection: null, promise: null };
}

export async function connectMongoose() {
  if (
    cached.connection &&
    cached.connection.readyState === ConnectionStates.connected
  ) {
    return cached.connection;
  }

  if (
    !cached.promise ||
    cached.connection.readyState !== ConnectionStates.connecting
  ) {
    cached.promise = connect(MONGODB_URI!, {
      maxIdleTimeMS: 10000,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 15000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 10000,
      connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
      maxPoolSize: 10,
    });
    cached.connection = await cached.promise;
  }

  return cached.connection;
}
```

**Screenshots of connection growth**

Initial number of connections:
[image]

Number of connections after I deploy the app and browse for a bit:
[image]

Comment: "I take care to cache and reuse connections". Sounds like you're trying to outsmart Mongoose's own connection handling.

Comment: @robertklep I've just tried this with a simplified version of the original code but the number of connections still jumped from 14 to 130.

```
import { connect } from "mongoose";

import { MONGODB_URI } from "@/utils";

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local",
  );
}

export async function connectMongoose() {
  return connect(MONGODB_URI!, {
    maxIdleTimeMS: 10000,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 15000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 10000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
    maxPoolSize: 10,
  });
}
```

Comment: Drop `connectMongoose()` entirely, just call `await connect()` _once_ at the start of your server.